# setCount not triggering rerender when called from interval

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to update some data on my website roughly once per second. Since I have been getting some strange behaviour, I added a counter to see what was happening. I have used google and tried suggestions, but most seem to reference setState, not useState.
I also came across seemingly conflicting information, some saying that useState triggers a rerender and others stating that the effects of useState are only "visible" after a rerender.

The result I am getting in the logs is that `count` is continuously 0, while `localCount` goes up. At some point I have looked at other tabs and must have done something to make the app rerender, because `count` was suddenly over 1000 (and staying at that number again), while `localCount` had started from 0 again.

I don't need `localCount` of course, if I could reliably use `setCount()` to update the count every second. But that has never worked for me. Updating the count in this way did work in the past. I am not sure what I changed that means it no longer does now.

Can I make sure that `setCount()` actually changes the count? Is the problem that I am trying to do it from an interval, and if so, is there a fix I can do?

The counter code I have looks like this:

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const everyTick = (count: number) => {
    setCount(count);
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let localCount = 0;
      let timer1 = setInterval(() => {
        everyTick(localCount);
        localCount++;
        console.log("localCount", localCount)
        console.log("count", count);
      }, 1000)
      return () => {
        clearInterval(timer1);
      };
  }, [])  

  return (
    // the html
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You are using stale value due to JS closures, `localCount` value is `0` in interval's callback closure. Please refer to duplicate question or research similar interval questions, its a common mistake.

Comment: I have tried the suggestion made in the other answer (`setCount((count) => count+1)` but it did not help. My count remains 0 wherever I check it. I have a `useEffect` method elsewhere that has `count` in the dependancy array and it does run every time count "changes", but the value of count remains 0.

Comment: For testing I am now showing the count on screen, and it does update. It is just within the code (console.logs and calculations) where count appears to remain 0.

Comment: Just put the example in codesandbox as simple as it